# is there a way to run the jquery.live function without any event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The live function of jQuery is triggered with an event 
The api documentation is here
http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$(".xyz").live('event', function(){
    });
```

I want the above function to run without an event , i.e as soon as the class xyz is dynamically created.

I have tried this without the event parameter

```
$(".xyz").live( function(){
    });
```

but it doesn't work !!

adding

Comment: `live()` was deprecated many years ago, and has been removed from jQuery, but no, there's no way to delegate events without events.

Comment: this can help you https://bocoup.com/weblog/publishsubscribe-with-jquery-custom-events

Comment: why use like that? can you tell reason for that?

Comment: @prasad i just want to manipulate a div , as soon as it dynamically created on my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but I'll make assumptions.

**Scenario 1**

In order to execute a function inside jQuery, you need to tell jQuery when to execute the function, otherwise it cannot know. One way to do this is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.xyz').css('color', 'red');
    // more code, anything, functions, calculations, etc.
});
```

The code inside that function will be executed as soon as your DOM is ready (is safe to manipulate).
You can put `$('.xyz').css('color', 'red');` also outside the `ready()` event and it will also be executed. The "event" this time is when the executions of the page reaches that line of code. For example, if you put this line before your HTML, you don't have guarantee it will work.

**Scenario 2 - `onClassChange` event**

If you are looking for an event called something like `onClassChange`, it does not exits on jQuery. An approach to that problem could be this:

- Create a timer which runs infinitely
- On each run, check if that object has your class ( `$(obj).hasClass('xyz')` )
- If yes, do whatever you want to do inside the `if ()`

Also, since you said the class `xyz` is created dynamically, you can try to run your function immediately after you create your class in your code.

For more about `onClassChange` event, there are long discussions you can check on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer , i really appreciate it (y)